# Displaying points from dataset within buffered areas of another using ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online

I'm very new to using ArcGIS Online and I am creating a map for a project I have in class.  I have plotted all Chicago Public Schools and want to display JUST all arrests that occurred within a 5-minute walking distance of them, and hide the rest of the datapoints.  How can I do this?

I have tried creating drive-time areas and joining features but that did not work properly.

This is the link to my map: https://arcg.is/1mbr9j

Comment: You had tags for ArcMap and ArcGIS Desktop but appear to be using ArcGIS Online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be on the right track. Here is how you would find all of the arrests within a five minute walk of a school:

1. Create drive time areas using walking distance.
2. Use Join Features under Summarize Data to select only those within that buffer.

This creates a new layer and appends a new attribute to the existing table (Join_Count).  Click the top row of the new column and select "Statistics" to get a count of arrests within a five minute walk of a school.